# GNU C++: unique_ptr.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, c++14

I am cross compiling some code from Windows on Linux machine (Kubuntu 16.05),g++ 5.4.0 64bit. Using Code Lite IDE as a dev env.
I have got several lines of code where I init unique pointer with

```
std::make_unique
```

The compiler complains with the error:

> error: 'make_unique' is not a member of 'std'

I tried to add `<memory>` as well as `<unique_ptr.h>` to the header. Then the compiler complains that it can't find `<unique_ptr.h>` file. Interestingly,when I click to open the file from within the editor it is found and opened. The file is located in  `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h`

I made sure that the compiler version that builds the code is indeed 5.4, so I don't understand why it doesn't support unique_ptr out of the box.I make sure to enable C++11 and C++14 flags:

```
-g;-O0;-std=c++14;-std=c++11;-Wall
```

Also, in the includes I add /user/include

What am I missing here? Do I have to include in the project the `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/` directory explicitly?

Comment: How do you set the flags? By enabling C++11, you may be disabling C++14.

Comment: Omg, I am feeling so stupid now. @juanchopanza you're have been right.I removed c++11 from the compiler options and the issue is gone. The Code Lite allows to check which c++ standards to support.I have been thinking that each of those enables standard specific features :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these flags:
`-g -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall`.  Note that semicolon is not needed for separating flags.

Compiler will take the latest entry of `-std` so you are effectively compiling with C++11 but not C++14.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [***HERE***](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GRyFkWX4NAnlacQW) enabling `-std=c++11` after a newer standard disables the first declared standard. Enabling only C++14 is enough.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 introduced `std::unique_ptr`, but there was no `std::make_unique` (this broke the "symmetry" of `shared_ptr`/`make_shared`).

They fixed that in **C++14**, adding `std::make_unique`.

So, if you compile your code in C++11 mode, you can't use `std::make_unique`.

As others already pointed out, you need to set the *latest* C++ standard with the `-std` compiler option; in this case, it's `-std=c++14` to enable *also* `std::make_unique`.